# Create csv file with Hashmap in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am fairly new to kotlin, and have wanted to change the way to save my CSV file. Currently my Hashmap is :

`private var Sdata:MutableMap<String, MutableList<String>> = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<String>>()`

and my data looks like this :

{a1 = [1:2:3:4, 1:2:3:4, ....], b2 = [1:2:3:4, 1:2:3:4,....]}

and my csv saving function:

```
binding.btnSave.setOnClickListener() {
        Sdata = viewModel.savehash
        Log.d(TAG, "CSV VIEW: ${Sdata.keys}")
        Log.d(TAG, "CSV VIEW: ${Sdata.values.size}")
        if(Sdata.keys.size != 0) {
            val csv = File(this.filesDir, "test1.csv") // Internal App storage

            val valuesSeparator = ","
            val lineTerminator = "\r\n"
            //write header, overwrite file if it has existed
            csv.writeText(
                Sdata.keys.joinToString(
                    separator = valuesSeparator,
                    postfix = lineTerminator
                )
            )
            val nRows = Sdata.values.maxOf { it?.size }    // size of list ar not all equal
            for (i in 0 until nRows) {
                val row = Sdata.values
                    .map { it.getOrElse(i) { "" }.trim() }
                    .joinToString(separator = valuesSeparator, postfix = lineTerminator)
                csv.appendText(row)
            }

            Toast.makeText(this, "Data Saved to Documents", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Logged Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

converts my files to look like this :
[image: CSV FILE]

I want to reiterate column values where column a1 has --> a1W, a1X, a1Y, a1Z and the values underneath are separated by the ":" delimters so that each single column is separated into 4 columns. Will this be difficult in Kotlin?
Any help would be greatly appreciated thankyou!!

Comment: CSV may seem like a simple format, but there are edge cases and quoting rules that can cause problems for naive implementations. Instead of reading or writing CSV yourself, it might be worth researching existing libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following for loop instead of yours should do the trick (*thanks @Joffrey for the hint*):

```kotlin
for (i in 0 until nRows) {
    val row = Sdata.flatMap { it.getOrElse(1) { "" }.trim().split(":") }
        .joinToString(separator = valuesSeparator, postfix = lineTerminator)
    csv.appendText(row)
}
```

Basically, you split your `1:2:3:4` values into a list containing the four numbers. And then your code should do the rest.

Comment: Why the extra step at the beginning instead of just replacing the existing `map` with a `flatMap`?

Comment: True, thanks for the hint. That would work since only the element to be retrieved with `getOrElse()` is needed. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thankyou so much again!

Comment: Thankyou so much again! Out of curiosity if I wanted to add a time column and I did not want that being separated by W,X,Y,Z would i have to make a different function?

Comment: I am not following you. Can you please explain better your use case with this "time column"? Additionally, if our answers helped you consider upvoting them ;) Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Sorry about that, thankyou again so much! I am sorry I did not upvote earlier!

Comment: No worries. You can also accept one of the answers so that your question can be ”closed” and others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you just need to slightly modify the way you create the headers row and the data rows.

For the header row, change the `Sdata.keys.joinToString(...)` into:

```kotlin
Sdata.keys
    .flatMap { listOf("${it}W", "${it}X", "${it}Y", "${it}Z") }
    .joinToString(separator = valuesSeparator, postfix = lineTerminator)
```

The `flatMap` call allows you to create a new list by converting each element (like `a1`) into a list of 4 elements (`a1W`, `a1X`...) and joining all those lists together into a big one.

For the data row, change the `.map { it.getOrElse(i) { "" }.trim() }` into:

```kotlin
.flatMap { it.getOrElse(i) { "" }.trim().split(":") }
```

Comment: Thankyou so much again! Out of curiosity if I wanted to add a time column and I did not want that being separated by W,X,Y,Z would i have to make a different function?